# How to add Element nodes to an XML file?

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SSMS 2008 R2 and am trying to convert the following XML:

```
<Provider>
    <NPI>1306875695</NPI>
    <FileCreationDate>2013-12-03</FileCreationDate>
    <FileCreationTime>13:51:09</FileCreationTime>
    <ProviderPatientNo>200543</ProviderPatientNo>
    <LastName>Hic</LastName>
    <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>12345</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
```

To:

```
<Provider>
    <NPI>1306875695</NPI>
    <FileCreationDate>2013-12-03</FileCreationDate>
    <FileCreationTime>13:51:09</FileCreationTime>

  <Patient>
    <ProviderPatientNo>200543</ProviderPatientNo>
    <LastName>Hic</LastName>

    <PhoneAssessment>
        <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>12345</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
```

How can I achieve this?  Here is my Tsql query:

```
select NPI, FIleCreationDate, FileCreationTime, ProviderPatientNo, LastName, ProviderPhoneAssessmentId 
from TN_DataFeed where lastname = 'hickman'

FOR XML RAW ('Provider'), ELEMENTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use RAW use PATH instead and name your columns appropriately:

```
select
    NPI,
    FileCreationDate,
    FileCreationTime,
    ProviderPatientNo 'Patient/ProviderPatientNo',
    LastName 'Patient/LastName',
    ProviderPhoneAssessmentId 'Patient/PhoneAssessment/ProviderPhoneAssessmentId'
from
    TN_DataFeed
where
    lastname = 'hickman'
FOR XML PATH ('Provider'), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need multiple levels.  How do I modify it according to my example above?